# ASCX page Button click not firing server side

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Master page which is inherited in a aspx page named Employee. Below is the relevant code of the aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Employee.aspx.cs" Inherits="ICA_Nagerbajar.Employee" MasterPageFile="~/Master.Master" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="e" TagName="Entry" Src="~/EmployeeView/EmployeeEntry.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="v" TagName="ViewEdit" Src="~/EmployeeView/EmployeeViewEdit.ascx" %>
<asp:Content ID="ContentBody" ContentPlaceHolderID="MasterBodyPlaceHolder" runat="server">

    <div class="tabbable">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li><a href="#tab1">Entry</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">View/Edit</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tabcontent">
            <asp:HiddenField ID="TabData" runat="server" />
            <div id="tab1" class="tab" style="display:inline-block">
                <e:Entry ID="EmpEntry" runat="server" />
            </div>

            <div id="tab2" class="tab" style="display:inline-block">
                <v:ViewEdit ID="EmpViewEdit" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Now in one of the ascx page (EmployeeEntry.ascx) Button is working fine. But in the other one(EmployeeViewEdit.ascx) it is not working. Below is the relevant code of EmployeeViewEdit.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EmployeeViewEdit.ascx.cs" Inherits="ICA_Nagerbajar.EmployeeView.EmployeeViewEdit" %>
<div class="boxed">
   <input id="TextBoxUserNameSearch" runat="server" class="textstyle" placeholder="Name" type="text"/>
   <asp:Button ID="ButtonSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" class="btnsubmitstyle" OnClick="ButtonSearch_Click"/>
</div>  

Server Side Code

  #region Search Button Click
        protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string userName = TextBoxUserNameSearch.Value.Trim();
            GetEmployee(userName + "%");
        }
  #endregion
```

**Few Observations i made**

1. If i replace Button with Link Button its working fine
2. No Button is working in this ascx though its working in the other ascx
3. If i comment out the first call to ascx in the parent page then the button is working ie, `<e:Entry ID="EmpEntry" runat="server" />`

Comment: What's in the `EmployeeEntry.ascx`? Could there be some javascript stopping button clicks?

Comment: The `asp:Button` should use `CssClass` for styling and not `class` that may get things confused. Have you tried using different form tags to narrow things down at all?

Comment: @JasonP - No sir there are no javascript which could block the call

Comment: @JB King - I made the change as you suggested but it didn't work. The form tag is in the Master page and not in any aspx or ascx page

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug and Fiddler to see if there is an issue in JavaScript, network or something else that could narrow down the issue?

Comment: @JBKing - Tried Fiddler sir but not sure what to look for. There are no javascript error in the page that is all i could find. Since the button click is not happening at all not sure what to look for. Any suggestion?

Comment: There are a few places where the error could be happening: In the browser, in the data sent to the server and in the server itself. The Fiddler check is to see that there is a request going back to the server. If there isn't then there is a JS problem on the page that narrows things down. Could there be an issue with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx (Which is the UserSubmitBehavior flag on the button instance)?

Comment: @JBKing - Thank you sir. Setting UseSubmitBehaviour="false" solved my problem.

Comment: Cuz the different classes of a `Button` and `LinkButton` may generate different JavaScript would be my initial thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @JBKing setting UseSubmitBehaviour property of the Button to "false" solved my problem

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" CssClass="btnsubmitstyle" OnClick="ButtonSearch_Click" UseSubmitBehaviour="false"/>
```